# Javascript: check if the referer url is exactly like

Tags: javascript

I use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            if(window.location.href.indexOf("https://www.exact-url.com/") > -1 
             || window.location.href.indexOf("/index.htm") > -1) {
               alert("Your are on the start page");
            }

        });
```

I want to know if the referer url ist the start page. They have two possible URLs. With `window.location.indexOf` is the first argument always true - because every refferer contains this URL.

How can I search exactly for the referrer? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is basically "How do I compare strings for equality?" Have you really done your thorough (or even basic) research before posting?

Comment: Separately: `window.location.href` is not the referrer.

Comment: what you exactly want? Do you want home page that is "Index.htm" then you just use second condition. It will be help full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get referrer by using `document.referrer`

```
var referer = document.referrer;
var refEscaped = escape(referrer);
```

So this will be what you need :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(document.referrer.indexOf("https://www.exact-url.com/") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("/index.htm") > -1) {
       alert("Your are on the start page");
    }
});
```